# Undefined Function PHP MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, function

I'm trying to figure out why I keep getting this error:

> PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function uniqueName() in/home/lear/public_html/storescripts/my_ipn.php on line 102

line 102 being

> if ( ! uniqueName($username))

```
require_once 'connect_to_mysql.php';

//now to always get unique username
$username = substr($payer_email, 0, strpos($payer_email, '@'));
if ( ! uniqueName($username))
{
    $username = makeUniqueName($username);
}


//function to check if is the existing username
function isUniqueName($username)
{
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT username FROM transactions WHERE username='$username'");
    $numRows = mysql_num_rows($sql);
    if ($numRows > 0)
    {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}


//function to generate new unique username
function makeUniqueName($username)
{
    //serch username string for number at the end
    //regexp makes sure all preceeding zeroes go to first match group
    if (preg_match('/^(\S*?0*)?(\d+?)$/', $username, $match))
    {
        //we got digit from the end of string, just add 1 to the digit
        $username = $match[1] . ($match[2] + 1);
    }
    else
    {
        //no digit at the end of string, just add digit 1 at the end
        $username = $username . 1;
    }

    if (isUniqueName($username))
    {
        return $username;
    }

    return makeUniqueName($username);
}
```

Comment: Do error messages get any more obvious than this?

Comment: Voting to close. This is way too specific and of no use to anyone else.

Comment: I'm not trying to be anything more than respectful, but when someone is trying to learn this type of response is very demoralizing.

Comment: @Chris I'm honestly not trying to demoralize you. But like Barmar said, the error could not be any more clear: `"Call to undefined function uniqueName() ...on line 102"`. So go to line 102. `uniqueName` hmm, Ctrl+F, "Oh look here's `isUniqueName`, I typed the wrong function name." There's no way this Q/A will be useful for anyone in the future, because it's about your specific code.  Just learn from the stupid mistake (we all make them!) and keep going, learning, writing, debugging.

Comment: Also, please don't make "additions" to your questions. If you have a different problem, please ask another question. Welcome to StackOverflow! I honestly hope you find this a useful resource (and motivation to learn!)

Comment: Oh no worries. I'm new to functions and a lot of more advanced PHP so I'm having some trouble. I can put together a site using PHP and MYSQL, but so new I have to do that then convert to MYSQLi using examples. I'm getting there, but its takign time. Thanks for the comment

Comment: lol I hear ya on the late night coding.

Comment: Deleted that comment but glad you took it positively ;)

Comment: Btw, you might be interested in using Eclipse to program in PHP. It supports various error checking and would have underlined this error. http://www.zend.com/en/company/community/pdt/downloads

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be `if ( ! isUniqueName($username))` and not `if ( ! uniqueName($username))`.  Note the `is` in front.

Comment: can you chat? I'm not able to initiate chat, but I'd like to ask you an off topic question.

Comment: @chris, what's the question?

Comment: It's about learning and debugging.

Comment: @Chris, here is the link: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34419/learning-and-debugging

Comment: I must have 20 rep to post so I won't be able to get in. Sorry for the confusion and effort.

Answer (score 1):

You're calling `uniqueName` but your method is called `isUniqueName`.

Answer (score 0):

Change the following  :

```
function isUniqueName($username)
```

to

```
function uniqueName($username)
```

and

```
if (isUniqueName($username))
{
    return $username;
}
```

to

```
if (uniqueName($username))
{
    return $username;
}
```

You have messed up while naming the functions.